# MYSQL modify record if blank

Tags: mysql

I've tried searching for my answer but likely don't know the correct phrase(s) to ask. Basically my database has situations where we don't leave the data blank for whatever reason (not my call). For example, we have a url column that is by default "http://" instead of just leaving it blank.

It makes auditing data without exporting and filtering a hassle when you have text that looks like something is there but really isn't. This is just one of a few cases. Is there any way in MYSQL to do an IF statement that will search for the string you know exists and switch it with "" BUT will not replace the values that aren't the string you are replacing?

I've seen IF ELSE statements but my issue with that is that the the other data is being modified which is not ideal since their url is very specific so an else is not ideal.

For example, I had the normal code with this result: [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2qIA.png)

But this is what happens when I try the IF statement (notice that the "http://" is gone, as I wanted, BUT the other organization URL's have been switched to whatever I put after the last comma): [Example Image](http://i.imgur.com/9ojB5H3)

I tried the alternative of not including an ELSE hoping that would help but I resulted in the following error:

**CODE:** *IF (o.url = "http://","") as "Web Site"*

**ERROR:** *MySQL Error 1064:: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as "Web Site" FROM organization o LEFT JOIN seed_organization_status ' at line 6 :: SQL:/* DirectQuery ID: 31 User ID: 64432 */ SELECT o.organization_id as "track code|link:organization", o.incorporation_dt as "Inc. Date|format:date", os.name as "Company Size", sos.name as "start-up", IF (o.url = "http://","") as "Web Site" FROM organization o LEFT JOIN seed_organization_status sos ON o.seed_organization_status_id=sos.id LEFT JOIN organization_size os ON o.organization_size_id=os.organization_size_id WHERE sos.name = "Start-Up" ORDER BY o.name*

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `IF (o.url = "http://","",o.url) as "Web Site"`

Comment: It turns out in the ELSE I could just type o.url and it places the original merged field in. I solved my own question through trial and error. Thanks for the sounding board, internets! :D

**Solution:** IF (o.url = "http://","",o.url) as "Web Site"

Comment: You beat me to it fyrye. Thanks anyways for looking and answering. :)

Comment: We don't have https show up. http:// is just the blank default value. If another value is entered that had https:// that would be followed by the url for the company so we wouldn't want to replace it. Thanks!